# size of file is not displaying in c

Tags: c

I am trying to get size of a file in c but my code isn't displaying any output with file size. Here is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<io.h>
#include<BIOS.H>
#include<DOS.H>

unsigned int handle;
void main()
{
    union REGS regs;
    unsigned long int size;
    handle = open("c:\\abc.txt",O_RDONLY);
    regs.x.bx = handle;
    regs.h.ah = 0x42;
    regs.h.al = 0x02;    //correction
    regs.x.cx = 0;
    regs.x.dx = 0;
    int86(0x21,&regs,&regs);
    *((int*)(&size)) = regs.x.ax;
    *(((int*)(&size))+1) =regs.x.dx;
    printf ("Size is %d" ,size);
}
```

Can someone please tell me why the output is not showing

Comment: What operating system, MS-DOS ?

Comment: What's wrong with the [`_stat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14h5k7ff%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) function?

Comment: When i run the program it dnt runs and also dnt show any error in code

Comment: It probably doesn't run because it doesn't allow programs to access the BIOS?

Comment: So what is should i do coz i have to display on console the size of file

Comment: is there any particular reason why you must use int21? btw use %ld for long int

Comment: Why you can't use slightly more portable way with [**ftell()**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/ftell/) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`fstat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/221w8e43%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void main( void )
{
   struct _stat buf;
   int fh, result;

   fh = _open( "c:\\abc.txt", O_RDONLY );

   /* Get data associated with "fh": */
   result = _fstat( fh, &buf );

   /* Check if statistics are valid: */
   if( result != 0 ) {
      printf( "Bad file handle\n" );
   } else {
      printf( "File size     : %ld\n", buf.st_size );
   }
   _close( fh );
}
```

Comment: `_fstat` should have a prototype

Comment: @user1685991 it has one in <sys/stat.h>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19198/discussion-between-user1685991-and-mux)